# Search pattern and print hits lower than threshold

Tags: arrays, awk, count

Here is an example what I need:

INPUT:

```
a 5
a 7
a 11
b 10
b 11
b 12
.
.
.
```

OUTPUT:

```
a 2
b 0
```

So on output should be hits lower than my threshold (in this case it is $2 < 10).

My code is:

```
awk 'OFS="\t" {v[$1]+=$2;  n[$1]++} END {for (l in n) {print l, n[l]} }' input
```

and my output is

```
a 3
b 3
```

I am not sure where to put condition `$2 < 10`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the threshold condition with something like `$2 < value`, where `value` is an `awk` variable given with `-v value=XX`.

Also, you are using `v[$1]+=$2`: this sums, not counts the matching cases.

All together, I would use this:

```
awk -v t=10 '{list[$1]} $2<t {count[$1]++} END {for (i in list) print i, count[i]+0}' file
```

Note we need to use two arrays: one to keep track of the counters and another one the keep track of all possible values.

#### Explanation

- `-v t=10` provide threshold.
- `{list[$1]}` keep track of all possible first fields appearing.
- `$2<t {count[$1]++}` if the 2nd field is smaller than the threshold, increment the counter.
- `END {for (i in list) print i, count[i]+0}` finally, loop through all the first fields and print the number of times they had a value lower than the threshold. The `count[i]+0` trick makes it print `0` if the value is not set.

#### Test

```
$ awk -v t=10 '{list[$1]} $2<t {count[$1]++} END {for (i in list) print i, count[i]+0}' a
a 2
b 0
```